# Create Azure ADF SHIR using bicep

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-bicep

I am trying to create DataFactory SelfHosted Runtime using bicep

I am trying to follow
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datafactory/2018-06-01/factories/integrationruntimes?pivots=deployment-language-bicep
There is ambiguity what all property needed to create SHIR. I need key based autorization.

Because to deploy IR msi on a VM we need Authkey which will be generated by above operation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/self-hosted-integration-runtime-automation-scripts

```
var parentName = 'someuniqueadfname'
resource SelfHostedIR 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/integrationRuntimes@2018-06-01' = {
name : '${parentName}/SelfHostedIR'
properties :  {
description : 'My Desc'
type : 'SelfHosted'
typeProperties : {
    linkedInfo : {
      authorizationType : 'Key'
      key : {
        type : 'SecureString'
        value : 'string'
      }
    }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code. This will be sufficient to create an IR which will be generating key for installation of IR agent in the Azure VM.

```
resource SelfHostedIR 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/integrationRuntimes@2018-06-01' = {
  name: '${parentName}/SelfHostedIR'
  parent: someuniqueadfname
  properties: {
    description: 'string'
      type: 'SelfHosted'
  typeProperties: {}
  }
}
```

Comment: type: 'string' is extra. Rest Worked perfect